# SVN in web development as a base code repository

Tags: php, model-view-controller, svn

I have been told that SVN is a good method of being able to manage multiple sites running from the same code base. I am struggling however to find out enough information about SVN and how it would be used in this way. Basically, I would look to put my ecommerce system into an SVN and then run it on multiple sites, each having specific configuration settings in order to specify allowed modules.

Could anyone advise me if 
(a) SVN is the correct method to do this 
(b) There is any material/tutorials out there on how best to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVN is a versioning tool, not a multi-site management tool. Although I can see how it can be used in that way, that is not what you get out of the box. You need an understanding of SVN first.

As an example, each website could have it's own svn branch of the code. Any updates that you want to propagate to the rest of the branches, you would merge with trunk, then update the rest of the branches.

That said, branching can very quickly get very complicated, especially with multiple developers. Git handles branching much better than SVN (my opinion). Git is also a versioning tool, just like SVN. But again, it's designed for versioning, bit multi-site management.

Comment: If site differentiated **only** by configuration's changes, I'll prefer SCM of **configs** *sepataely* and separate one repo from base engine

Comment: I think im probably much further away than I thought and need to do more research as to the correct solution

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you could treat each installation as a working copy of the SVN repository, log in to each system, and do a checkout from the latest code on the SVN server.

I do not recommend this approach.  It will be slow and will pollute your application folders with a bunch of svn data that you do not need on your web server.  You do not want to risk by putting it insider your web root.

I recommend using rsync.  With rsync, pushing out updates is slightly more complicated than copying a local file.  If you are running linux, the odds are that rsync is already on your system.  On windows you can run it under cygwin or find various alternative implementations, such as DeltaCopy.

If for some reason you can't use rsync won't work, I would recommend SFTP.

Comment: Wanted downote, but re-think... **Never** use WC as part of web-space. Only cleaned exported copy

Comment: @LazyBadger, did you read the second paragraph?  I clearly recommend against using SVN.  I've never been downvoted because someone agrees with me.